# Кто сказал Main'у что Controller – контроллер?

Tags: java, архитектура, javafx

Я создал новый проект JavaFX в IntelliJ IDEA, и IDEA сделала мне 3 файла: Main.java, Controller.java, sample.fxml.

Как между собой связаны классы Main и Controller? В Main нет никаких упоминаний о Conroller; Controller ничего не наследует, не помечен никакими аннотациями...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сам только познаю JavaFX, и возможно сам где-то ошибусь:

Controller присваивается `fxml` файлу свойством `fx:controller` корневому элементу.

Сам же контроллер должен имплементировать интерфейс `Initializable`, 
в методе  `public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)` которого происходит инициализация элементов при запуске и присваиванием им каких то параметров.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, я нашёл, это прописано в sample.fxml:

```
 fx:controller="sample.Controller"
```